# Recursive Least Squares in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, numpy, recursion

I'm pretty new to Python and trying to make a RLS filter work. I have a simple linear forecasting regression `d = b*x + v` for which I would like to recursively estimate `d` by incorporating the data for `x` one at a time and measure the error of the filters estimate to the actual `d`. The filter examples online look like this:

```
N = 500

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, (N, 4)) # input matrix

v = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N) # noise

d = 2*x[:,0] + 0.1*x[:,1] - 4*x[:,2] + 0.5*x[:,3] + v # target identification

f = pa.filters.FilterRLS(n=4, mu=0.1, w="random")

y, e, w = f.run(d, x)
```

But how do I make this work? I don't have a matrix for `x`, I only have a simple regression with one independent variable. And why do I need to give the noise `v`, that's something I would like to get from the filter? I would like to give actual data for `x` and `d` as an input.